# Can I use the first OR last 16 characters of a Guid and it still be unique?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

### Objective

Generate a unique 16-character key, to use as a batch name, that doesn't require any type of storage (**e.g.** a unique counter).

### Background

I have a Windows service that runs **every 30 seconds**. I picks up messages off of an MQ and processes them in a batch. One of the service calls I'm making is requiring a 16-character batch name now. **They don't care what the batch name is**, it just needs to be unique across all batches.

### Question

If I generate a [`Guid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx), can I use the first or last 16 characters of that string and it still be unique for my needs?

Comment: Use a TimeStamp with (at least) a 1 second resolution. Readable and sortable as a bonus.

Comment: `Readable and sortable as a bonus`, good point @HenkHolterman.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No is the simple answer. Why not use the date/time?

For example, here's some Oracle generated GUIDs

```
D71CDF38BB3B6026E0430A9A9A286026
D71CDF38BB3C6026E0430A9A9A286026
D71CDF38BB3D6026E0430A9A9A286026
D71CDF38BB3E6026E0430A9A9A286026
D71CDF38BB3F6026E0430A9A9A286026
D71CDF38BB406026E0430A9A9A286026
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll be using this format to get my batch name - `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmm-ss")` - it's down to the seconds so it can't be duplicated that way.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud, good idea, these types of names will be helpful when debugging. You might want to add a random bit on the end though. Windows GUIDS are pretty random, so in combination with date and time you could use 6 digits from that.

Comment: @Ben, I won't be able to add anything more because it can only be 16 characters and that's already 16 characters. But that's okay, like you said, this will be good for debugging because when reading logs we'll know what batch they are out of just by looking at the date and time.

Answer (score 6):

No.

Raymond Chen explains why in great detail in [GUIDs are globally unique, but substrings of GUIDs aren't](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/06/27/8659071.aspx).

However, if you are running this on a single machine, then you don't need your ID to be *globally* unique - merely locally unique. Therefore, you can drop the MAC address requirement from the GUID algorithm he describes. Also, if you know that only one will be generated every 30 seconds, you can drop the collision part of the algorithm. This pretty much leaves you using the date-time as qujck suggests.

Comment: There is more than one GUID algorithm... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier#Algorithm

Comment: Yes - but I doubt any of them will allow you to simply chop half the length of and still retain the property of global uniqueness. If they *did* allow that then they would be, by definition, overspecified by 100%...

Comment: Guaranteed global uniqueness is not a property that GUIDs have - even V1 guids do not have it because (in real life as opposed to theory) duplicate MAC addresses have been issued in error, so the spatial component intended to guarantee uniqueness is busted. All they have is a statistical likelihood of uniqueness, for which purpose the question is not "is it certain to avoid collisions" but "is it likely enough to avoid collisions". In the birthday problem we expect collisions to begin after 2^(N/2), so 64-bit random numbers are expected to collide on average after about 2^32 are generated.